# How can i stop the process of searching for new devices in wifi network?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates, nsnetservice

in my wifi network code i am using a ***NSNetServiceBrowser*** delegate **searchForServicesOfType** which will starts a search for services of the specified type in the domain indicated by domainString

[**self.netServiceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:types inDomain:domain]**

my case type is network identifier(string:"**_tcp_wifi**") and domain is "**local**"(string).

For each service discovered, a -netServiceBrowser:foundService:moreComing: message is sent to the NSNetServiceBrowser instance's delegate.

**- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing {
}**

above delegate will trigger for each service discovered .

**searchForServicesOfType** delegate will always search for the new devices.
however i need to stop the process of searching for new devices after 2 minutes using a timer.is it possible do this.is there any NSNetServiceBrowser delegate to do this? if yes ,can any one tell me the good way to do it.

Comment: [self.browser searchForServicesOfType:@""inDomain:@""]; what to use to get all device names in network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop a search, use the stop method. You should perform any necessary cleanup in the netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch: delegate callback.

Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/BrowsingForServices.html)

Comment: i think stop method will not stop searching process .it will only Halts a service which is either publishing or resolving.

Comment: i think the below delegate will trigger after i stop searching.
- (void)netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser;

Comment: but no idea about how to stop search

Comment: got it /* Stops the currently running search.
*/
- (void)stop;